# hide a folder path when user downloads a file

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am using wordpress for my website and there are some wallpapers in my folder which i provide for download . But i dont want users to know the exact file location of folder . As there is a subscription for the download.

suppose my file is stored in

```
http://www.example.com/wp-content/example.folder/awesome.png
```

Now how to hide the folder name `example.folder` and use any fake name, That dosent shows up while downloading . Really need a big help on this. can anyone suggest me a good method. I tried some wordpress plugins , but no help on this.

Comment: The most secure thing to do is to put the file in a directory that apache does not serve (outside of your root web folder), then have PHP open the file and output it to the browser. You can use `fopen()` or `readfile()` for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example With PDF doc

```
$nameOld = "/public_html/wp-content/example.folder/oldnme.pdf";
$nameNew = "newName.pdf" ;
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$nameNew"); //
readfile($nameOld);
```

**Edit**
Prove of Concept for your image system using `download.php?img=flower` without the extension and `flower` show be the image name

```
$directory = "/public_html/wp-content/example.folder/";
$types = array("jpg","gif","png");
$ext = null;

if (! isset($_GET['img'])) {
    die("Invalid URL");
}

$nameOld = filter_var($_GET['img'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);
$nameNew = uniqid(basename($nameOld));

// File the file
foreach ( $types as $type ) {
    if (is_file($nameOld . "." . $type)) {
        $ext = $type;
        break;
    }
}

if ($ext == null) {
    die("Sorry Image Not Found");
}
$nameOld .= "." . $ext;
$type = image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($nameOld));

header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Content-type: ' . $type);
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$nameNew"); //
readfile($nameOld);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but where i have to put this code and what about if there are number of files but a same folder .and i want to change the folder path or hide it or fake it. Your example is for one file

Comment: just crate a `download.php` it would download the image anytime you visit that page

Comment: but its like i have multiple wallpapers and when user clicks on any of them , then the particular file gets download

Comment: in the same folder. when i click on any wallpaper one of the above example link gets fired up and the wallpaper gets download , how to wrap up your code with this
?

Comment: One more thing .. are they all jpeg files ??

Comment: @ParamVeer you got an answer - now you should: 1) accept it and 2) do the "dirty work" - don't accept people here on SO to "work for you"!

Comment: Sorry i didnt meant to ask anyone to work for me @Baba was asking me some thing i just replied to that. i just wanted to know i case of multiple images what can be done .

Comment: @Baba thank you for helping out . M sorry if you felt i was asking you to work everything out for me. I was having problem with multiple images.

Comment: One correction: `accept` => `expect` (my brain was running forward and my fingers where moving on their own...) :)